# how to send email to gmail from Swift Mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, swiftmailer

I am using `Swift Mail` library to send email from my website.

The code is working perfectly fine and its successfully sent emails to my domain email, but most of the times it does not send email to my `gmail` or `Hotmail` address.

Let say i sent 3 email from my website,i receive all 3 in my `domain inbox`, but only 1 email or sometimes no email recieve by my `gmail` or `hotmail` account.

I am using `godaddy` hosting.

Kindly guide me what i am doing wrong here.

```
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Lagos');

$name=      $_REQUEST['name'];
$user_message=  $_REQUEST['comment'];
$email=     $_REQUEST['email'];


// Create the mail transport configuration
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setTo(array(
  "info@domainName.com" => "DomainName",
  "myGmailId@gmail.com" => "Kirmani"
));
$message->setSubject("Email from Easenook");
$message->setBody("$user_message");
$message->setFrom("$email", "$name");

// Send the email
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->send($message);


echo 'sent';
```

Comment: Have you checked Spam folder in Gmail?

Comment: Yes i checked it, In `hotmail`I receive emails in spam folder, but in `gmail` it send emails in inbox, but most of the times it doesn't send any email